# Unix Untar a File Into a Directory

Tags: unix, tar

I am trying to decompress a tar (.TGZ) file, but want to decompress it into a new directory called `newdir`.

The command I am using to decompress is: `tar –xzf filename.tgz`

How can I expand that to decompress it into `newdir`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the `-C` option (or `--directory`, it is the same):

```
tar –xzf filename.tgz -C /target/directory
```

---

From `man tar`:

> **-C, --directory DIR**
>
> change to directory DIR

Comment: watch out for tar bombs and you probably want to add `v` to your list of flags.

Comment: Thanks, but I know what is inside these files - which is why I leave it out.  Sound advice though!